# Can I live in the UK with a German passport?

Tags: united-kingdom

So I have a German passport,and i want to *live* in the UK, is that possible? Or do I have to get a visa, or something like that?

Comment: Right now yes. Answering what will happen after the March 29, 2017 is speculation.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Are you saying that Brexit has already set the UK back by over a year? ;)

Comment: Until March 29, 2019 (not 2017), definitely yes. Until Dec. 31st 2020, very likely yes. After that, pure speculation. Your chances of being allowed to stay when you are already there are much better than your chances of being allowed to enter to stay.

Answer (score 9):

As long as the UK is in the EU, you can live there without visa. What happens when Brexit takes effect is not certain, but in all likelihood you will require some sort of visa. Having been an UK resident prior to Brexit may or may not help you get that visa afterwards.

[Brexit negotiations are ongoing](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-46318565), but it is a good guess that it will happen by March 29th, 2019.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear what the arrangements will be after Brexit, but currently as a German citizen you have the right of free movement throughout the EU, which for the time being includes the United Kingdom. You are free to settle without requiring a visa, or even a job offer.